# Optimizing airflow dag

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, parallel-processing, airflow

I am new to `Apache Airflow`. I have created an airflow dag in which there are couple of image processing tasks running in parallel. Basically, I am trying to read a PDF (consisting of 10 pages), converting each page into image parallely, do some image processing on each page and dump the output into `JSON` (after combining output for every single page). Check the image below:

[image]

So far I have used ***local executor*** ***(default configuration)*** ***running on top of 8 core cpu (single machine)***. The process took around **40 mins** to complete.
I have also tweaked the configuration by changing `max_threads` to `8`, `parallelism` to `8` and `dag_concurrency` to `8`. *It took around 20 mins*.

I expect the whole process to complete within *5-10 mins* for the same number of pages. Is it possible using current executor configuration ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As you you running local executor, Can you add more information about how the processing tasks actually run, are you processing all image one function call at once or the function handles one image at a time? If later, `dag_concurrency` is to set default concurrency of your dag, `parallelism` control the number of task instances per airflow installation, you can definitely try to bump them up. You can refer more here https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#how-can-my-airflow-dag-run-faster

Comment: Hi Chengzhi . Thanks for replying. Edited the question and added a screenshot of what is going on in the dag. Can you please check and suggest what should be done.

Comment: A few things, 1) after get_pdf, can you scale to more pages by adding more downstream jobs to run more page-xxx task concurrently? 2) Noticed you have some task with a yellow circle which is retry, is that expected? Do you have log for one of the jobs that retried

Comment: 1. This was just for 5 pages. There are certainly more than 5 pages in the dag. 2. The yellow (retried ones) are undesirable. While checking the logs, they got scheduled but didn't actually run. So there were no logs for those tasks. But eventually they get completed. This might happen due to the concurrency parameter. BTW Thanks for replying @Chengzhi

Comment: If you have more pages, you can definitely add more as downstream and you would need to bump up `concurrency` for that dag, default is `dag_concurrency` from config but you can set it at dag level.

Comment: Thanks will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Chengzhi. Sofar increasing the concurrency parameter did not help. By using pools for certain tasks I have managed to decrease the time by 5 mins. Currently for 10 pages the dag takes about 15 mins to complete. Can it be reduced down to 5 mins. Thanks again.

Comment: Are those 10 pages start to run at the same time? Do you mean a single parsing page task will take 15 mins?

Comment: No @Chengzhi the total process (10 pages) takes about 17-20 minutes to complete but a single page takes about 7 minute to complete.

Comment: There is also `non_pooled_task_slot_count1 in airflow.cfg that you might want to check. I'd suggest you can run those 10 pages in parallel first, meaning make sure these10 pages start to run at the same time in airflow. However, since a single page takes more than 7 mins, if you want to optimize that, I think you would need to revisit your function of parsing the page to see if you can tune there instead of tune airflow concurrency settings.

Comment: Thanks @Chengzhi. Checked my parsing code without airflow. For 1 page it takes about 2 mins. In airflow it takes 7 min. Probably due to latency between two task communication this might be happening (saw in gantt chart that there is a 1 min gap between two tasks). Can it be reduced. Thanks.

Comment: I see, there could be more configs you'd need to check, however, airflow needs to check multiple things before it can schedule a new task, it won't happen right away. I'd suggest you check `scheduler_heartbeat_sec` in airflow.cfg and parallelism settings, maybe paste your airflow.cfg and dag here to help you better.